# module configuration in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, frameworks, multi-module

I'm working with multi-modules CMS in Zend Framework. I want to create a structure like this:

```
testsite/
index.php
library/
    zend/
    test/
application/
    configs/
        application.ini
    modules/
        users/
            controllers/
            models/
        ....
    frontend/
        controllers/
        models/
        ....
    backend/
        controllers/
        models/
        ...
    bootstrap.php
```

I have created the following code:

```
//in application.ini
resources.frontController.defaultModule = "frontend"
resources.frontController.defaultControllerName = "index"
resources.frontController.defaultAction = "index"
resources.frontController.plugins.init = "Test_Controller_Plugin_Initializer"

//in bootstrap.php
 protected function _initControllers()
{
    $this->bootstrap('frontController');
    $this->_front = $this->getResource('frontController');

    $this->_front->addControllerDirectory(APPLICATION_PATH . '/backend/controllers', 'backend');
    $this->_front->addControllerDirectory(APPLICATION_PATH . '/frontend/controllers', 'frontend');
}

 //in Test/controllers/plugin/initializer.php
 public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
{          
    $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $request = $front->getRequest();

    $request->setModuleName('frontend');
    $request->setControllerName('index');
    $request->setActionName('index');
}
```

It does not work when I go to my base URL `.../testsite`. Can you please let me know where I went wrong?

Comment: show what u have in .htaccess file

Comment: in my .htaccess, i have code like this:                       RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

Comment: It looks like you have a security problem. Index.php in the `/testsite/` directory which makes everything in your application potentially servable. Not a good Idea. you should at least implement a public or html directory and put your application outside of your docroot.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting your modules in the modules directory?
ie:

```
testsite/
index.php
library/
    zend/
    test/
application/
    configs/
        application.ini
    modules/
        users/
            controllers/
            models/
        ....
        frontend/
            controllers/
            models/
            ....
        backend/
            controllers/
            models/
            ...
    bootstrap.php
```

Wich is typically where zf expects to find its modules. You might have to adjust you rapplication.ini settings to reflect this.

Comment: i know this typical configuration. but i want to do something different.

Answer (score 0):

To make this work how you want it to refer to [Zend_Application_Resource_Frontcontroller](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.frontcontroller)

specifically you need to pass an array of *'module' => 'controller'* directory pairs to `resources.frontController.controllerDirectory`.

> ***controllerDirectory:*** either a string value specifying a single
>   controller directory, or an array of module to controller directory
>   pairs.

I doubt this will solve all the problems but it should head you in the right direction.